# dynamic mail configuration using Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel application, I am trying to send mail notification based on the company_id of the logged in user:

I have this:

```
$mail=DB::table('mail_settings')->first();
$config = array(
           'driver' => $mail->driver,
           'host' => $mail->host,
           'port' => $mail->port,
           'from' => array('address' => $mail->from_address, 'name' => $mail->from_name),
           'encryption' => $mail->encryption,
           'username' => $mail->username,
           'password' => $mail->password,
           'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
           'pretend' => false
       );
Config::set('mail',$config);
```

Models

```
class Company extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'companies';
   protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'organization_name'
  ];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
   protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'company_id',
    'email',
 ];
}
```

Is there any way to override default mail configuration (in app/config/mail.php) on-the-fly (e.g. configuration is stored in database) before mailer transport is created?

Thanks

Is there any way to recreate laravel swiftmailer transport so it can pick up updated config values?

Answer (score 0):

The `Mailer` class is created in the `Illuminate\Mail\MailManager` class's `resolve()` method. If you want to dynamically create a mailer, you need to adapt this function in your Controller to use your `$config` array and return a `Mailer` from which you could chain the usual methods.

```
protected function resolve($name)
{
    $config = $this->getConfig($name);

    if (is_null($config)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Mailer [{$name}] is not defined.");
    }

    // Once we have created the mailer instance we will set a container instance
    // on the mailer. This allows us to resolve mailer classes via containers
    // for maximum testability on said classes instead of passing Closures.
    $mailer = new Mailer(
        $name,
        $this->app['view'],
        $this->createSwiftMailer($config),
        $this->app['events']
    );

    if ($this->app->bound('queue')) {
        $mailer->setQueue($this->app['queue']);
    }

    // Next we will set all of the global addresses on this mailer, which allows
    // for easy unification of all "from" addresses as well as easy debugging
    // of sent messages since these will be sent to a single email address.
    foreach (['from', 'reply_to', 'to', 'return_path'] as $type) {
        $this->setGlobalAddress($mailer, $config, $type);
    }

    return $mailer;
}
```